# all internal links won't work in a local-wamp site even after .HTaccess and mod_rewrite setup

Tags: navigation

I've imported a Drupal 7.41 existing site to my local machine on a wamp server. I've already imported it's .HTaccess (uncustomized), and have enabled mod_rewrite in WAMP and restarted all services.

Yet, anytime I click on one of the internal links at the local site, I get, is some, 404 error, and in some WSOD.

When I tried to log in via localhost:8095/yoyo I got this error after filling the details and clicking on the log in button, I've seen the following error, but I don't know should I do with it exactly? (Adding some kind of a class manually?) Updating the theme maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 404 errors on any internal links, have you edited the /rewritebase in htaccess? If the site now resides in a file, or in the root, this may need commenting out, or enabling.

As for the error. Are you certain you copied all files correctly?

Also, are you certain your mySql was dumped correctly?

Steps to try and fix can be...

1. Move files again.
2. Try dropping and reimporting the database.
3. Running [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild). Note: this is not a module, this is something you can run with drush, or by placing the php in your directory and accessing it.
4. Try following this guys comment https://www.drupal.org/node/1323786#comment-5305922

Comment: Indeed it was a registry issue. About the link you pasted --- last comment; I understand right that the guy brought that code manually form a fresh install registry table? Thanks.